# pass a specific node into ESLint options

Tags: eslint

In ESLint, you can access specific nodes in the abstract syntax tree generated from your code via the Esprima parser with keywords like `ExpressionStatement` and `VariableDeclarator`. I want to develop an assert function that will allow me to pass a specific node into the `options` of ESLint.

```
function validateExpressionStatement(context){
  return {
    context.options[1]: function (node) {
      var source = context.getSource();
      var sourceEval = eval(source);
      if (!(sourceEval == context.options[0])) {
        assertOk(false, "", `Expected a return value of ${context.options[0]}.`);
      }
      else {
        assertOk(true, `${context.options[0]} was returned correctly.`)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My assert will push a value entered by the user into the options array so I then can choose which node I want to check before testing my code.

```
function assertExpressionStatementReturn(value, treelevel){
    config["rules"]["validate-expression-statement"][1] = value;
    config["rules"]["validate-expression-statemet"][2] = treelevel;
}
```

In this particular function I'm checking if the return value from a specific node in the AST with my assert. I know the `context.options[1]` will not work. Is there a way to achieve this? If I need to clarify what I'm looking for at all please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood what you are asking for, but there are already a few rules in ESLint repository that do that. For example `comma-style` can accept list of AST Node types as exceptions. The code is located [here](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/lib/rules/comma-style.js#L21).